# Replacing pressure switch for my water pump

Tags: plumbing, pump, well

I have to drain the pressure tank when I replace the pressure switch. When I do this can I install a shut off valve just below the pressure switch? This would allow me to change it in future years and avoid draining the tank.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the down side.  The pressure switch, generally speaking has a very long life, many, many years.  So they have to be renewed relatively seldom.  And if you put an isolation valve between the switch and the main water line and it accidentally get turned off you really mess things up and cost yourself $1000's.  Better to have to drain the tank down.